# How to add only numeric numbers in a column C#

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbdatareader

I would like to get the total sum of a DataTable column in C#. However, my column consist of both string and numeric values. Is there a way to sum up only numeric values found in the column?

**DataTable**

```
Column

hello
304
-312
213
bye
```

I have tried using the code below but it will not work when there the cell is not in numeric value.

```
var total = dt.Compute("Sum(column)","");
```

Comment: What database is this reading from?

Comment: why not reading rows and parsing all String data, using accumulator and `sum += decimal.TryParse(dt["Column"][i].ToString(), out var value) ? value : 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
decimal sum;
for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
  sum += decimal.TryParse(dt["Column"][i].ToString(), out var value) ? value : (decimal)0L;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use casting in `Compute` so a solution could be something like this (VB.net code):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("test")

dt.Rows.Add("hello")
dt.Rows.Add("304")
dt.Rows.Add("-312")
dt.Rows.Add("213")
dt.Rows.Add("bye")

Dim intTotal As Integer = 0

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

    Dim intValue As Integer = 0

    If Integer.TryParse(dr("test"), intValue) Then
        intTotal += intValue
    End If

Next dr

MsgBox(intTotal)
```

Comment: Agreed, if DB designed so badly that it contains mix of textual and data information, better to do it manually

Comment: Thanks for the answer it work well! however it is in VB.net so i'll accept the one that is in C# code instead.

Answer (score 0):

C# example

```
Datatable dt = new DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("test")
dt.Rows.Add("test2")
dt.Rows.Add("45")
dt.Rows.Add("12")
dt.Rows.Add("-213")
dt.Rows.Add("test3")

int total = 0

Foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    If (Integer.TryParse(dr("test")){
        total += dr("test").value)
    }
}

return total;
```

Answer (score -1):

The Compute method allows type conversion.

```
var sum = dt.Compute("Sum(Convert(column, 'System.Int32'))");
```

You can also  use LINQ:

```
int sum = dt.Rows.Select(dr=>(int)dr["column"]).Sum();
```

For more informations: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataColumn_Expression)

Comment: what if someone place doubles or floats int database as well as integers?

Comment: `int sum = dt.Rows.Select(dr=>(int)dr["column"]).Sum();` will raise an exception on string data, not convertible to int implicitly